# Actualizar datos en una tabla usando CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Trabajo con SQL Server 2008 Tengo una tabla `tmpEmpleado` la cual tengo que actualizar sus datos con una tabla `Equivalencias`, tengo el siguiente código.

```
declare @tmpEmpleado table (EntretenimientoId int, FirstName varchar(100));
Insert into @tmpEmpleado(EntretenimientoId, FirstName)
values
(1,'Nancy'), 
(2,'Andrew'), 
(3,'Janet'), 
(4,'Steven');

DECLARE @Equivalencias TABLE(Id int, NombreEquivalente VARCHAR(100))
INSERT into @equivalencias(Id, NombreEquivalente) VALUES(2, 'Batman')
,(4, 'Superman')
,(1, ' ')

update tmp
set tmp.FirstName = 
(case
    when e.NombreEquivalente <> '' then e.NombreEquivalente
    else tmp.FirstName
    end
)
from @tmpEmpleado tmp
join @Equivalencias e on tmp.EntretenimientoId = e.Id 

select * from @tmpEmpleado
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

```
EntretenimientoId FirstName
----------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                 Nancy
2                 Batman
3                 Janet
4                 Superman
```

Sale el resultado que espero

> ¿Hay alguna mejor manera de hacerlo?

Tengo que usar `UPDATE` esa es una de las condiciones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No actualizar las filas que no van a cambiar. Esto implica poner un where en la update.

```
declare @tmpEmpleado table (EntretenimientoId int, FirstName varchar(100));
Insert into @tmpEmpleado(EntretenimientoId, FirstName)
values
(1,'Nancy'), 
(2,'Andrew'), 
(3,'Janet'), 
(4,'Steven');

DECLARE @Equivalencias TABLE(Id int, NombreEquivalente VARCHAR(100))
INSERT into @equivalencias(Id, NombreEquivalente) VALUES(2, 'Batman')
,(4, 'Superman')
,(1, ' ')

update tmp
set tmp.FirstName = e.NombreEquivalente
from @tmpEmpleado tmp
join @Equivalencias e on tmp.EntretenimientoId = e.Id 
Where len(isnull(e.NombreEquivalente,''))>0
```